# What do you call people who repair your vehicles and jump out to scare you?

Tags: riddle

I need help with this riddle:

> What do you call people who repair your vehicles and jump out to scare you?

It's 2 words and "we don't call them that and we think they're quite ethical."

Comment: Is it a riddle or a jokey pun say like rot13(fngnavp zrpunavpf)?

Comment: From what i know its a riddle but the pun could be possibility.

Comment: Rot13 (Abg n crefba, ohg znlor n whzc fgnegre?)

Answer (score 5):

> Surprise Mechanics...

Good one ARandomPerson

Comment: "What do you call **people** who repair your vehicles and jump out to scare you?"

Comment: @Duck Yes, I think this is the answer -- a mechanic is a person who repairs vehicles. (And it's referring to a recent comment from EA on their rebranding of "lootboxes" as "surprise mechanics".)

Comment: surprises are good, bring scared is bad

Answer (score 1):

How about a "**jump starter**"?

It may not *exactly* fit the question, but:

- You can use one to 'repair' a car if the battery is flat.
- If someone scares you unexpectedly you have experienced a "jump
  start".